# Universal Links from Closed App not working

Tags: swift, appdelegate, ios-universal-links

I have my app set-up to handle Universal links. We handle the retrieval of the URL, and the navigation given the URL inside of this function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        guard NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb == userActivity.activityType, let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return false
        }
        // Do navigation to correct page based on URL
        return true
    }
```

This works perfectly for us when our app was previous running in the background, and a universal link is tapped.

However, when I kill the app completely and click on a universal link, this function doesn't appear to be running and so it doesn't handle the universal link at all, it just brings the user to the home tab.

I've tried grabbing the URL in `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` and `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])` but neither of those seem to get called as well.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out what's happening here? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Did you find the issue??? I am also facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift 5 IOS 14** When app is terminated use

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Get URL components from the incoming user activity.
        guard let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first,
              userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
              let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL
        else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            LinkHandler.sharedInstance.handleLink(url: incomingURL)
        }
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works and it blows my mind

Comment: u r the best <3

Comment: Does iOS15 still need this hack?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in

`func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`

You can get the URL by checking `connectionOptions.userActivities` (it's a `Set<NSUserActivity>`).

Get the URL from `webpageURL`
Here's the example:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    for userActivity in connectionOptions.userActivities where userActivity.webpageURL != nil {
        // call your universal link handler here
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On `application(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` url is inside an options.
Please test it again.

Apple docs:
launchOptions
A dictionary indicating the reason the app was launched (if any). The contents of this dictionary may be empty in situations where the user launched the app directly. For information about the possible keys in this dictionary and how to handle them, see Launch Options Keys.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application